# Special Characters will not be removed from XML via XLST

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, special-characters

I can't seem to get some special characters removed an XML.  They are an ellipsis, a double quote, and single quote.  I am escaping the special characters and have a period in my list as well, but it won't remove.  Everything else removes but these few items.

Here's the XLST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
        version="2.0">

        <xsl:template match="/"> 
            <soa:Label identifier="6f109b37-d9d1-4ff3-8e16-7ecffa08be1f" name="To Avid Transcript" description="" instance="b885c5f1-6307-42ff-a79c-42d61bc4464e" signature="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core">
                <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="32bd5202-f003-4da3-8d1f-2b5a5d324af9" bindable="True" name="Transcript" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false">
                    <xsl:variable name = "apos">'</xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(Transcript, '♪!@#&amp;&quot;&lt;&gt;$%^*()[]{}?/.,:;™-', '')"/>
                </soa:Parameter>
            </soa:Label>
        </xsl:template>         

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here's a portion of the XML:

```
<Transcript>[1:45] JD: : Hi, I’m John Doe, executive vice president. Right now you are tuning in to a very special Program, “Program Name.” seeing in the world today...</Transcript>
```

The transform results currently look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<soa:Label identifier="6f109b37-d9d1-4ff3-8e16-7ecffa08be1f" name="To Avid Transcript" description="" instance="b885c5f1-6307-42ff-a79c-42d61bc4464e" signature="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core">


145 JDY  Hi I’m John Doe executive vice president Right now you are tuning in to a very special Progra “Program Name” seeing in the world today...

</soa:Parameter>
</soa:Label>
```

As you can see those certain characters are not being removed.  Any help would be great.

Comment: The characters `’`, `“`, and `”` aren't in your `translate()`. If you add them they should work. I don't see an ellipsis in your example; only three periods.

Comment: From my understanding, I have the escape the special characters like doubles quotes are &quot;, so I can't use ' and ".  I have a period listed so I don't know why it's not removing the three periods.

Comment: Like Michael pointed out in his answer, you're not using quot or apos in your XML, you're using smart quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input contains "smart quotes". To remove these, use:

```
translate(Transcript, '&#8216;&#8217;&#8220;&#8221;', '')
```

I wasn't able to reproduce your problem regarding the period.

Comment: Great, that worked.  I just found the same unicode like you had listed above for the ellipsis and it removed it too.

Comment: @RyanJensen Good. Note that the numerical character references are used only for convenience and clarity. You could just as well use the actual characters, e.g. `translate(Transcript, '‘’“”', '')`.